# Custom download Manager having issue when my ListView goes up & down?

Tags: android, listview, video, android-listview, android-asynctask

> I am developing a Custom Download Manager and getting an issue when ListView scroll UP & DOWN?

I am using Base Adapter for the custom ListView. Only one video / 1st video in the row is downloading and after completeion one second will start.

**What is the Main problem:**

For the downloading I am using AsyncTask. If I have 2 or 3 video in the downling list, "Downloading / completion working fine".

`But in case if I have 10 video in the downloading list. 5 video is appearing in list first time. First video downloading start`.

> > Now what happen IF i scroll down for checking the below list and scroll up. Automatically from 6 to 10 number video , one video auto download start and when I pause the First video the auto start video also pause.

I checked weather the AsyncTask is recall or not but It is not recalling.

**So, from one reference of AsyncTask two video download parallel. [I checked,  there is only one reference]**

Somebody tell me is there any way to handle this situation or whatever which is feasible to make it possible.

If you are not getting what is my problem please write a comment. I'll make it easy whatever from my side

Answer (score 0):

Are you using viewholder in your ListView.

Comment: nope , I am implementing the row from a different class which wxtends the LinearLayout